# How to find the mean for each row with different number of values

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Class   Budget  Total   Rank                                    
A        120    1926    58     5    9      2       10      3                
B        120    3146    52     6    15     55      6       7    8   9       
C        120    2358    51     0.9  -6     0.5                      
D        120    3252    57     33   16     0.5     9       7    6   3   4   6
```

I want to get the mean for each row starting from the value after the Rank. To do that, I tried the following:

```
data[, "Mean"] <- rowMeans(data[, 5:length(data)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

and I also tried:

```
data[, "Mean"] <- apply(data[, 5:length(data)], 1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In both cases, I get the following results:

```
Class      Mean
A          5.857143
B          18.555556      #the correct mean is 15.1428571429
C          -1.940000      #the correct mean is -1.5333333333
D          10.727273      #the correct mean is 9.3888888889
```

The mean of the first class is correct but the other are not correct.

Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Your Row C contains only positive numbers yet you report that it is getting (and should get) a negative mean.

Comment: @G5W Sorry, there was a mistake in the numbers in the dataset. I changed them to the correct ones.

Comment: Please share `dput` of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
mean_row <- rowMeans(data[, 5:ncol(data)], na.rm = TRUE)
     mean_row
[1]  5.800000 15.142857 -1.533333  9.388889
```

So:

```
data$mean_row <- rowMeans(data[, 5:ncol(data)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

With data:

```
data <- read.table(text = "
Class   Budget  Total   Rank   a    b      c       d       e   f    g   h   i    
A        120    1926    58     5    9      2       10      3    NA  NA  NA  NA      
B        120    3146    52     6    15     55      6       7    8   9   NA  NA      
C        120    2358    51     0.9  -6     0.5     NA      NA   NA  NA  NA  NA               
D        120    3252    57     33   16     0.5     9       7    6   3   4   6
                ",header = T)
```